# Styling child <li> using class selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

The title might be confusing. I had a question in my paper that said:

Write an HTML fragment to which the following CSS rule will apply:

```
li > .ext {

 color: blue; }
```

I answered it like :

```
<div class="ext">
  <ul>
    <li> This is a list item </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

But later I thought it could be like:

```
<div >
  <ul class="ext">
    <li> This is a list item </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

As the li is direct descendant of ul. But none of these worked. Can anybody explain the error?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Write an HTML fragment to which the following CSS rule will apply:

```
li > .ext {

 color: blue; }
```

It would be something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li> <span class="ext">This is a list item</span> </li>
 </ul>
```

The structure of the selector requires an element **with** a class of `.ext` that is a **direct child** (`>`) of an `li`.

[**30 CSS Selectors You Should Memorise**](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: "direct child (`>`) "...plus, you know, the link.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the meaning of this (>) selector. I thought it means select all <li> where parent  class is ext. Thanks for the quick answer..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of direct descendant.

```
li > .ext
```

Means find the child element, one level down, that has a class of '.ext'.

A direct descendant will only look one level down.

```
<ul>
    <li>This is a list item
        <p class="ext">This is what will be selected</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel the reason it's not working is because there is some more powerful css selector exists than yours, means the existing css selector is taking priority.

Wrote an example for you, how this is happen: 
http://codepen.io/tusharbhatta/pen/dpqwAj
Here a special top level div class 'bug' is taking the precedence over your code:

```
.bug ul li > span {
  color: red;
}
```

I would suggest to enable debug mode and select that li html and see which selector is being executed by the browser. That will give you the clue.

Comment: Firstly, your "answer" should be a comment not an answer and secondly, you seem to have misunderstood what the OP was asking. See the *actual* answers.

Comment: @Paulie_D, He is asking an explanation. Looks like you didn't read the question.

Comment: No....it's quite clear...he has to **write** HTML that satisfies the selector he's been given... **Thats** what he's having trouble with, not specificity or priority or debugging.

Comment: I have improved the answer adding example to explain. Hope that will further help you @Abby

Comment: Thanks @Tushar for the explanation :)